# JS events listener: OnBlur event: result depends on what was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a date input box with a pop-up calendar date selector. When I click on the date box the popup calendar appears. Then I can either

- Select a date. The date appears in the date box and the calendar appears
- Click outside the calendar. The calendar disappears. This is via a `mouseup` event that checks what was clicked.
- Type a date in the date box.

What I want: When I type a date in the date box and tab away, then I want the calendar to disappear. I have tried this by adding an `onBlur` event to the date box. This event made the calendar go away. However, this means that the calendar disappears when I click inside the calendar, which I don't want. So I need some kind of date box `onBlur` event that checks whether the calendar was clicked/has focus. Or something else altogether.

I tried to check whether the calendar has focus. Using jQuery I did:

```
target = $("*:focus");
```

This did nothing useful. Normally I'd use an `onCLick` event to see what was clicked, but then I'd need an `OnClick` and an `OnBlur` event and the `OnBlur` event would need the result of the `onClick` event. However, I don't seem to be able to control what gets called first.

I tried using  the Chrome and IE JS debuggers to see what is going on, but adding breakpoints seem to change what functions are called, which makes no sense. Adding a breakpoint in the `onBlur` event: it stops there. Adding a breakpoint in the `mouseUp` event: it stops there. Adding a breakpoint in both events: it only stops in the `onBlur` event even though I do continue. I have to click a second time to trigger the `mouseUp` event.

Comment: Can you please post the relevant calendar markup?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/alaa13212/Gs5Y2/

to use `blur` focusout in jQuery.
must focus on element (use `tabindex` attribute for focusable)